# Do we have to close the session object?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

Do we have to close the session after its usage? As I understood SessionFactory closes sessions if it needed. For example:

```
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public long count(String extId) {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) session
                    .createSQLQuery(
                            "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM smsc.queue WHERE extId=:extId AND nextId IS NULL")
                    .setString("extId", extId).uniqueResult();
            return count.longValue();
        }
```

This is my DAO method called in my services. Does that mean I have to close session every time?

Comment: yes...make it a habit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When you are finished with it you should close it. You need not explicitly close it yourself, there are frameworks that can do this for you.
It is not an expensive operation to open and close sessions. It is usually problematic keeping them open too long as your cached session data grows more stale over time.
A Session is opened when getCurrentSession() is called for the first time and closed when the transaction ends. It is also flushed automatically before the transaction commits.

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

Answer (score 0):

Use this general formula to close connection in your code

```
try {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    // Do stuff with connection.
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

Check more [here](http://blog.shinetech.com/2007/08/04/how-to-close-jdbc-resources-properly-every-time/)